# First Hitting Times of Brownian Motion have independent increments.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

As I read the proof of [Theorem 7.4.1 in Rick Durrett: Probability: Theory and Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fxbY.jpg):

[image: 1]

I am confused about why a step is possible. The theorem with the proof is given in the linked picture. $T_a = \inf \{s \ge 0 \mid B_s = a\}$ is the first hitting time of a standard Brownian motion $B = (B_t)_{t\ge 0}$. $P_x$ is defined as
$$
P_x(B_{t_1} \in A_1,\dots B_{t_n} \in A_n) := P(B_{t_1}+x \in A_1,\dots B_{t_n}+x \in A_n),
$$
where $0 \le t_1 < \cdots < t_n$, $n\in \mathbb N$. $E_x(\cdot)$ denotes the corresponding expectation value. $\theta_s$ is the shift transformation. I can follow all the steps shown in the picture, without these one: Why can we pull out the conditional expectation in the last step of the last equation:
$$
E_0 \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} F_i E_0(F_n \vert \mathcal F_{T_{a_{n-1}}}) \right) \stackrel{?}{=} E_0 \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} F_i \right) E_0(F_n)
$$
Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: $F_n$ is independent of $\mathcal F_{T_{a_n-1}}$.

Comment: The proof of that step is just above in the picture.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer :) This used in the first equal sign. Because $F_n$ is independent of $\mathcal F_{T_{a_{n-1}}}$ we have $F_n = E_0(F_n \vert \mathcal F_{T_{a_{n-1}}})$. But why can  pull this outside of the outer expectation ?

Comment: Ahh.. I messed up a few things about the conditional expectation. Silly. Thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation: From the intermediate step of the proof, we know that

$$ E_0(F_n\mid\mathcal{F}_{T_{a_{n-1}}}) = E_0(f_n(T_{a_n} - T_{a_{n-1}})\mid\mathcal{F}_{T_{a_{n-1}}}) = E_0(f_n(T_{a_n-a_{n-1}})) \qquad P_0\text{-a.s.} \tag{1} $$

Since the right-hand side of $\text{(1)}$ is constant, $E_0(F_n\mid\mathcal{F}_{T_{a_{n-1}}})$ is a constant random variable and hence is equal to its expectation:

$$ E_0(F_n\mid\mathcal{F}_{T_{a_{n-1}}}) = E_0(E_0(F_n\mid\mathcal{F}_{T_{a_{n-1}}})) = E_0(F_n) \qquad P_0\text{-a.s.} $$

Therefore it follows that

$$ E_0\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} F_i\right)
= E_0\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} F_i E_0(F_n \mid F_{T_{a_{n-1}}})\right)
= E_0\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} F_i E_0(F_n)\right)
= E_0\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} F_i\right) E_0(F_n). $$

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my questenion is given in the comments:

In the first equal sign of the last equation, it is used that $F_n$ is $\mathcal F_{T_{a_{n-1}}}$ measurable. Then in the second step, the independence of $F_n$ and $\mathcal F_{T_{a_{n-1}}}$ is used.

Comment: $F_n$ is *not* $\mathcal{F}_{T_{a_{n-1}}}$-measurable, since it involves $T_{a_n}$ that require information after the time $T_{a_{n-1}}$. Actually, quite the opposite is true: $F_n$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{T_{a_{n-1}}}$.